# Ошибки при запуске сервера на node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, npm

Запускаю проект `npm start`. Выдает такое вот:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! path C:\JavaScript\AngularJS\Projects\loftblog_angular_phonecat_app\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\JavaScript\AngularJS\Projects\loftblog_angular_phonecat_app\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\JavaScript\AngularJS\Projects\loftblog_angular_phonecat_app\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\JavaScript\AngularJS\Projects\loftblog_angular_phonecat_app\npm-debug.log
```

Возможно здесь что то банальное. Но я новичок во всем этом. Заранее спасибо за помощь. Запускаю вот [этот проект](https://github.com/Severenit/loftblog_angular_phonecat_app).

Comment: В проекте нет файла `package.json`, о чём вам и сообщает npm. А зачем вы выполняете эту команду?

Comment: @РоманПарадеев мне нужно запустить сервер, чтобы зайти на него через браузер(например).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из README к указанному вами проекту:

> и не забудьте что никакого сервера здесь не установлено, здесь только исходные файлы, которые должны быть помещены в корень вашего локального сервера.

Поэтому, чтобы запустить это приложение, нужно сначала установить какой-нибудь веб-сервер, например, так:

- В каталоге с проектом выполните команду `npm init`. На все впоросы, которые будет задавать эта команда, просто нажимайте Enter.
- Установите веб-сервер [lite-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server): `npm install lite-server --save-dev`.
- Если еще не выполнили, запустите `bower install`.
- Отредактируйте файл `package.json`, добавив в `"scripts"` скрипт start:

  ```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  ```
- Теперь можно запускать: `npm start`.

Answer (score 1):

Веб-сервер не включён в состав проекта.

Если у вас установлен python или php, можно использовать их встроенные серверы. Для этого нужно перейти в папку с проектом и выполнить одну из перечисленных ниже команд.

Для php:

```
php -S localhost:80
```

Для python 2:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

Для python 3:

```
python -m http.server 80
```